# a disk read error occurred press ctrl+alt+del to restart windows 7 laptop after installing ubuntu 13.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I have a dell inspiron N5010 laptop. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 along side with windows in another partition. After restarting my laptop it is showing 'windows 7(loader)' but an error is occurred while loading. My Ubuntu 13.04 is working great. Can any help me out with my problem.

Comment: What error message ? You can try boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by reinstalling the Windows bootloader as my main/default bootloader and then adding the Linux bootloader (probably GRUB 2 for Ubuntu users) to the Windows bootloader.

**To fix Windows bootloader and make it the default:**

For Vista and 7:

1. Boot with the Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation disc.
2. Click Repair your computer.
3. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
4. In the System Recovery Options window, click Command Prompt.
5. Type Bootrec /fixmbr to repair the Master Boot Record .
6. Type Bootrec /fixboot to repair the Boot sector.
7. Type Exit and then click restart.

Source / read more: http://www.raymond.cc/blog/help-a-disk-read-error-occurred-press-ctrlaltdelete-to-restart/#ixzz2gFAT6bWf

**To add Linux to Windows's bootloader**

Boot into now-bootable Windows and install EasyBCD (free for personal use).  Click "Add New Entry", click the Linux tab, choose "GRUB 2" for the type, select the option to automatically find the drive and click "Add Entry".

Source / read more: https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager